# Strange functioning of RegionPlot with Reduce's output

Tags: equation-solving, plotting

I have defined this two quantities:

```
f = (-b + Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a])/(2 a)
g = (-b - Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a])/(2 a)
```

and I want to solve this system in function of $a$, for $f,g$ complex: $$\begin{cases} |f(a,b)|>1 \\ |g(a,b)|>1 \\ Im(a)=Im(b)=0 \end{cases}$$

So I use:

```
Reduce[Abs[f] > 1 && Abs[g] > 1 && Im[a] == 0 &&  Im[b] == 0, a, Complexes]
```

getting the solution I seached.

[image: total solution]

Now, I want to split the regions where the square root in the equation of $f,g$ is positive or negative. If I use:

```
Reduce[Abs[f] > 1 && Abs[g] > 1 && Im[a] == 0 &&   Im[b] == 0 && (Re[b^2 + 4 a] >= 0 || 
Re[b^2 + 4 a] < 0) , a, Complexes]
```

I got the same result as before, and this is true.
My ploblem is that if a solve separately

```
Reduce[Abs[f] > 1 && Abs[g] > 1 && Im[a] == 0 && Im[b] == 0 &&   Re[b^2 + 4 a] >= 0 , a, Complexes]
Reduce[Abs[f] > 1 && Abs[g] > 1 && Im[a] == 0 && Im[b] == 0 &&   Re[b^2 + 4 a] < 0 , a, Complexes]
```

and I plot the results using RegionPlot a small area disapears.

[image: solutions missing]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Öskå Thank you for your answer. I added MaxRecursion to the options of RegionPlot and I fixed the problem. Can you explain me why without it RegionPlot does not work?

Comment: See [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html) for the details :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html):

```
f = (-b + Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a])/(2 a);
g = (-b - Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a])/(2 a);
RegionPlot[{
  Reduce[Abs[f] > 1 && Abs[g] > 1 && Im[a] == 0 && 
             Im[b] == 0 && Re[b^2 + 4 a] >= 0, a, Complexes],
  Reduce[Abs[f] > 1 && Abs[g] > 1 && Im[a] == 0 && 
             Im[b] == 0 && Re[b^2 + 4 a] < 0, a, Complexes]}, {a, -2, 2}, {b, -3, 3}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 7, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the option `Evaluated -> True` for RegionPlot? I was not able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: @TaikiBessho, Try it without, and you will see the difference :) You can always look for the `Evaluated` documentation.